# Адрес сайта кириллицей брать в кавычки?

Tags: выбор-варианта

Сайт герои-живы.рф заключать в кавычки при написании в тексте?

Comment: Полностью название сайта не пробовали дать?

Comment: И второй вопрос: как выглядит фраза?

Comment: Для участия в конкурсе регистрируйтесь на сайте герои-живы.рф.

Comment: Это полное название сайта...

Comment: Полное имя — с http://www. Чтобы не размышлять о кавычках. Http://www.герои-живы.рф.